# What is the nicest a Unix command can be?

Tags: performance, nice, ionice

For a quick benchmarking test, how can nice and ionice be combined to maximum effect, ie for a command to use as little resource as possible (without idling altogether)?

*(I think it's something like `nice -n 19 ionice -c 2 [command], but not sure about ionice's "-n" (classdata param), the man page is cryptic about its relevance.)*

Comment: plus 1 for the clever question title, but it's also a good question in general.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The full command you want is:

```
chrt -b 0 nice -n 19 ionice -c 2 -n 7 [command]
```

The `chrt` command at the beginning will switch things to the batch scheduling class, which is equivalent to adding 0.5 to the nice value.  The -n option for ionice is a simple priority for the realtime (`-c 1`) and best-effort (`-c 2`) options, with lower values being higher priority just like nice values (but in the range 0-7).  However, the ionice command is not strictly necessary, since I/O scheduling class and priority are by default derived from the CPU scheduling parameters, and `nice -n 19` implies `ionice -c 2 -n 7`.

However, you can get the absolute minimal resource usage by setting both the CPU and I/O scheduling classes to idle.  In both cases, the 'idle' schedulers aren't actually idle schedulers, and you will still be able to use resources, it's just that everything will have higher priority.

For the CPU scheduling class, this also uses the `chrt` command, albeit without needing `nice` (priority must be set to `0` in the idle scheduling class), and looks like this:

```
chrt -i 0 {command or PID}
```

The `nice` command on Linux mirrors the SVR4 version, which means that it can't change scheduling class, only nice value (which also behaves differently on Linux than classical UNIX, but that's a bit OT).  As the original alternative scheduling classes were the POSIX.1E realtime `SCHED_RR` and `SCHED_FIFO`, the command to set scheduling classes ended up being called `chrt`.  The `-i` option specifies to use the `SCHED_IDLE` scheduling class

For the I/O scheduling class, you use `ionice`.  The exact command looks like this:

```
ionice -c 3 {command or PID}
```

The `-c` option specifies what scheduling class to use, and 3 is the number for the idle class.  Note that depending on which block I/O scheduler is being used, this may not actually impact anything.  In particular, the `noop` I/O scheduler doesn't support priorities or scheduling classes at all, and I'm pretty sure the `deadline` schedulers (both the legacy one, and the blk-mq one) don't either.

If you want to do this programmatically, either for your own program, or to adjust things for other processes, check out the man pages for the `sched_setscheduler` and `ioprio_set` system calls (although both are worth reading if you just want more background too).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want that command to completely wait for others to finish, so not to potentially suffer [resource starvation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starvation_(computer_science)), the line would be:

```
nice -n19 [command]
```

As [ionice](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ionice.1.html) will be set proportionally on modern Linux kernels.

By the way `chrt -b0` has nothing to do with niceness, but to how often the CPU will jump from one process to another. This line makes that time longer for batch programs to make better use of caches, but for other commands it's useless. As seen [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/sched-design-CFS.txt).